# Use argument twice from standard output pipelining

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a command line tool which receives two arguments:

```
TOOL  arg1 -o arg2
```

I would like to invoke it with the same argument provided it for arg1 and arg2, and to make that easy for me, i thought i would do:

```
each <arg1_value> | TOOL $1 -o $1
```

but that doesn't work, $1 is not replaced, but  is added once to the end of the commandline.

An explicit example, performing:

`cp fileA fileA`

returns an error **fileA and fileA are identical (not copied)**
While performing:

`echo fileA | cp $1 $1`

returns the following error:
**usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory**

any ideas?

Comment: we'll need to see something closer to your actual argument values. As is, we can't tell if your argument values are causing the problem, or if you have a misbehaving `tool`. (Given your description of reusing `$1`, I can't see any way that `bash` would have a problem with that). (Please edit your Q with some close to actual arg values. ). Good luck!

Comment: `each <arg1_value> | tool $1 -o $1` pipes the output of the `each` command to the standard input of `tool`. The piping does nothing with the command line of `tool`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Can you give expected results?  You can't copy a file on top of itself, and `cp` isn't really geared to receive data through a pipeline, so it is unclear what your "explicit example" is supposed to do.  (Also, you have _three_ arguments. What is `-o`? Is `arg2` an option to that second argument?)

Comment: Please explain what that `each` command does, (or provide a link to a man page).

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you need, but `a="$1"; TOOL "$a" -o "$a"` will allow you to use the variable as often as required. If you must pipe, remember each pipe runs in its own *subshell*. Piping pipes `stdout` from the previous program to `stdin` of the next process. Your alternative with pipes would be `each arg1_val | read -r arg; TOOL "$arg" -o "$arg"`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use xargs, the [-I] option may help:

```
-I replace-str
              Replace  occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separa‐
              tor is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

Here is a simple example:

```
mkdir test && cd test && touch tmp
ls | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' '{}'
```

Returns an Error **cp: tmp and tmp are the same file**

Answer (score 4):

The `xargs` utility will duplicate its input stream to replace all placeholders in its argument if you use the `-I` flag:

```
$ echo hello | xargs -I XXX echo XXX XXX XXX
hello hello hello
```

The placeholder `XXX` (may be any string) is replaced with the entire line of input from the input stream to `xargs`, so if we give it two lines:

```
$ printf "hello\nworld\n" | xargs -I XXX echo XXX XXX XXX
hello hello hello
world world world
```

You may use this with your tool:

```
$ generate_args | xargs -I XXX TOOL XXX -o XXX
```

Where `generate_args` is a script, command or shell function that generates arguments for your tool.

The reason

```
each <arg1_value> | TOOL $1 -o $1
```

did not work, apart from `each` not being a command that I recognise, is that `$1` expands to the first positional parameter of the current shell or function.

The following would have worked:

```
set - "arg1_value"
TOOL "$1" -o "$1"
```

because that sets the value of `$1` before calling you tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-run a shell to perform variable expansion, with `sh -c`. The `-c` takes an argument which is command to run in a shell, performing expansion. Next arguments of `sh` will be interpreted as $0, $1, and so on, to use in the `-c`. For example:

`sh -c 'echo $1, i repeat: $1' foo bar baz` will print execute `echo $1, i repeat: $1` with $1 set to `bar` ($0 is set to `foo` and $2 to `baz`), finally printing `bar, i repeat: bar`

Answer (score 1):

The `$1,$2...$N` are only visible to bash script to interpret arguments to those scripts and won't work the way you want them to.  Piping redirects `stdout` to `stdin` and is not what you are looking for either.

If you just want a one-liner, use something like

> ARG1=hello && tool $ARG1 $ARG1

Comment: This works, thanks. Is there a solution which involves xargs as well? I like pipelining since the input might come as a result of a previous script.

Comment: Probably, I don't use xargs. stdin doesn't have anything to do with arguments, so piping has nothing to do with it. If you get the output from a subshell like `ARG1=$(previous_script.sh) && tool $ARG1 $ARG1`

Answer (score 1):

Double up the data from a pipe, and feed it to a command *two* at a time, using **sed** and **xargs**:

```
seq 5 | sed p | xargs -L 2 echo
```

Output:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

Comment: On consideration, this works but Jiangty's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to use STDIN four times, to print a multiplication table:

```
seq 5 | parallel 'echo {} \* {} = $(( {} * {} ))'
```

Output:

```
1 * 1 = 1
2 * 2 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 5 = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

One could encapsulate the tool using `awk`:

```
$ echo arg1 arg2 | awk '{ system("echo TOOL " $1 " -o " $2) }'
TOOL arg1 -o arg2
```

Remove the `echo` within the `system()` call and `TOOL` should be executed in accordance with requirements:

```
echo arg1 arg2 | awk '{ system("TOOL " $1 " -o " $2) }'
```